# What is 'target' in 'target = open(...)'

Tags: python

I'm learning Python as someone more familiar with databases and ETL. I'm not sure where `target` comes from in the following code.

```
from sys import argv
script, filename = argv

target = open(filename, 'w')
```

I think `argv` is a class in the `sys` module, but I don't think `target` comes from `argv`.

Comment: That's just a variable name. They could have called it almost anything they wanted.

Comment: `target` is a file object. See e.g. https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open

Comment: `argv` is actually just a `list`.

Comment: target is the name of the variable. using target variable  you can access the file method's `target.read()` etc

Comment: [`sys.argv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.argv): *The list of command line arguments passed to a Python script.*

Answer (score 0):

If you run `type(target)`, you will get this: `<_io.TextIOWrapper name='dde-recommendation-engine/sample_data/synthetic-micro/ratings.txt' mode='r' encoding='UTF-8'>`

What that means in simple terms is that it is an object accessing that particular file (with only write permission because you have a `w` mode).

You can use this object to add stuff into the file by `target.write(.....)`

Do remember to close the file however by doing `target.close()` at the end.

Another way to do the same and I prefer this most of the times is:

```
with open(filename, 'w') as target:
    target.write(...)
```

This way the file is closed automatically once you are out of the `with` context.

Answer (score 0):

argv is the list populated by the arguments provided by user while running the program from shell. Please see https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.argv for more info on that.

User supplied the filename from shell, program used the open call https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open to get a file handle on that filename

And that file handle is stored in variable called target (which could be named anything you like) so that you can process the file using other file methods.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `open()` - **[a built-in function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open)** in python. This function returns an **[File object](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-file-object)** - which is assigned to `target` variable. Now you can interact with `target` to write data (since you are using the `w` mode)
.